# Can I make Google Play not run a background process (on CM10)?

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, ram, processes

There is always a background process for Google Play Market in the CyanogenMod 10 system (Android 4.1.x). I don't like this. Since my device (Samsung Galaxy S) doesn't have much memory, I'd like to make it not run in the background.

Instead I'd like it to run only when started manually to install a new app or check for updates, or from time to time (to give it the possibility to sync).

Is this possible without de-installing Goolge Play?

Answer (score 2):

I think Google Play is bundled with some services that requires for another applications.
 ie : Applications that uses Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

According to this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html

> GCM requires devices running Android 2.2 or higher that also have the **Google Play Store application installed**....

So basically, Google play is not there only for install a new app or check for updates etc.. So I think it's better to leave it as it is.

Comment: Perhaps, [Greenify](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/87124/13117) could be of some help. In that answer, it is said that it would still allow to receive GCM. I wonder whether it will really alleviate the pressure for resources on the device. (The device is rooted.)